# AD Groups for Windows User

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, directoryservices

I have an asp.net MVC application which is configured to use windows authentication. I am trying to get Groups from UserPrincipal using this.

```
UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups()
```

This works fine when running from Visual Studio but fails when hosted on IIS. App pool is configured for Integrated pipeline and Network Service Identity. Throws below error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'."

I tried impersonating the code

```
WindowsIdentity identity = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

using (WindowsImpersonationContext wic = identity.Impersonate())
{
     PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN NAME");
     UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "User Name");

}
```

FindByIdentity throws error.

> 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E8, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1

How can I get current user groups from AD?

Comment: how did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up having this problem because i accidentally had my authentication types for the IIS site set up wrong.  I removed 'anonymous authentication', and had it set so only 'asp.net authentication' and 'windows authentication' were enabled, and the error went away.